How to prevent wp_localize_script from localize the ajax URL in the array?
Currently in my WordPress plugin, I use wp_localize_script to pass data from PHP to JS, as below:
    wp_localize_script($this->plugin_name, 'MyObj', array(
        'ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
    ));

It works properly in English post with a shortcode of the plugin. However, in the Chinese post with the same shortcode, it does not. After tracing the data, I find in the Chinese post, the ajax_url will be added a language slug.
For example, if the English post is https://www.example.com/blogs/jpg-to-png/, then the ajax_url will be https://www.example.com/blogs/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php, which is correct.
But in the Chinese version, https://www.example.com/zh-CN/blogs/jpg-to-png/, then ajax_url will also be changed to https://www.example.com/zh-CN/blogs/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php, which is not desired.
How to prevent this? I try to pass the root_url, admin_url, but wp_localize_script will always add the language slug for the Chinese post. How to keep the data intact when passing it from PHP to JS?
Update:
I add the following log lines to check if the ajax url passed to wp_localize_script is correct:
    error_log('ajax url via admin_url: ' . admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ));
    error_log('ajax url via site_url: ' . site_url('wp-admin/admin-ajax.php'));
    
// Localize script to pass AJAX URL
wp_localize_script($this->plugin_name, 'MyObj', array(
    'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
));

and then add the following log lines to check if the ajax url gotten by the JavaScript code is correct:
console.log("Ajax url: ", MyObj.ajax_url);

Then in debug.log, it shows:
[16-Aug-2024 14:51:02 UTC] ajax url via admin_url: https://www.example.com/blogs/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php
[16-Aug-2024 14:51:02 UTC] ajax url via site_url: https://www.example.com/blogs/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php

So when they passed to wp_localize_script, they are all OK.
But in console log, it shows:
Ajax url: https://www.example.com/zh-CN/blogs/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php

So it is wp_localize_script that change the ajax url and add the lang slug.
Currently our website is using GTranslate plugin to support multi-languages.

If you ask me, it is not wp_localize_script that adds the language slug. It is admin_url that does this. How did you setup the languages? Is this done via a plugin? If so which plugin? And did you try contacting the makers of this plugin to help sort this out?

As a quick workaround, you can simply remove the language slug like this: str_replace('/zh-CN', '', admin_url('admin-ajax.php')).

You can also replace admin_url('admin-ajax.php') with site_url('wp-admin/admin-ajax.php') … See How to prevent wp_localize_script from localize the ajax URL in the array? describing some effective workarounds.

@Klaassiek, Thank you. I have updated the post to show that it is wp_localize_script that change the ajax URL. Also I want the script to work with other languages, so simply remove '/zh-CN' will not work for other languages.

@LoicTheAztec, I have made more logs and it show both admin_url('admin-ajax.php') and site_url('wp-admin/admin-ajax.php') will return correct ajax url before calling wp_localize_script, but after calling wp_localize_script and pass to JS, it has the language slug

I’m not familiar with the GTranslate plugin. It could accomplish this behaviour in different ways. A quick-and-dirty workaround would be to convert part of the url to some gibberish string, and then convert it back before using it in javascript. For example, you could replace « http » in the url: str_replace('http', 'temporary_placeholder', admin_url('admin-ajax.php')). Then before using it in javascript reverse this by doing let theUrl = MyObj.ajax_url.replace('temporary_placeholder', 'http'). This might prevent the plugin from changing your url.

(You should adjust my proposed code for cases where the url contains « http » multiple times, for example in the domain name « the-http-tutorial.com »)

@alancc So maybe you can filter this Ajax URL on the JavaScript Ajax code by replacing MyObj.ajax_url, with MyObj.ajax_url.toString().replace('zh-CN/blogs/', ''), which will remove zh-CN/blogs/ from the URL.

@Klaassiek, Thank you for your trick.

@LoicTheAztec, the zh-CN is only an example, I want to work for all languages, totally 103, it is unlikely to implement 103 replacement statement do the task.
